# clean up html code

Tags: html, tidy

Hi i am looking for a script to simply line up my html code (opening and closing tags line up etc)

i have tried tidyHTML and a few web based solutions but they all stuff up my grid system and php includes by removing or changing elements i just want something that will tidy the tab indents so its easier to read not change the markup.

also i have seen that htmlTIDY has config options but i just find them confusing if I'm missing something and i can set it up to not change markup an example or tutorial would be appreciated.

any suggestions would be great.

I use Coda if that helps

Comment: what text editor do you use ?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you want your html displayed

Comment: Dreamweaver has "apply source formatting" which is helpful if you have it.

Comment: i tried to add example but it showed up weird in the post

Answer (score 0):

Try the answers of [formatting html code using sublime text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/formatting-html-code-using-sublime-text-2) .

Also, you could try [tidy-html5](http://w3c.github.com/tidy-html5/) from the w3c.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2015 for CODA

For non-destructive and HTML5-validated Tidy-ing of your HTML code:

1. Install the Coda PHP & Web Toolkit plugin by Mario Fischer, v4.2beta
2. Go to it's Preferences and choose W3C, Configuration: Custom
3. Adjust the HTML Tidy config-file to your needs, add the 'block' element for example
4. Documentation is here: http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#docs