# Sublime Text 2: Format HTML tags' content in one line

Tags: sublimetext2

Ok, my situation is a bit different than all the threads here about formatting HTML. Also, I've installed about every HTML formatting plugin out there with mixed results and none really solve my issue.

Also, configuring these plugins can be difficult since I'm not a programmer and some authors don't provide enough information to customize their plugins.

For now the only plugin that formats my HTML somewhat Ok is **[HTMLTidy](https://github.com/welovewordpress/SublimeHtmlTidy)**, the problem is that it uses too much space per tag. See my HTML example below.

I also tried what they mentioned in **[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/formatting-html-code-using-sublime-text-2)** and it only works to some extent as far as indentation goes, but not really for 'true' markup formatting.

All I want to do is turn this markup:

```
<ul>
   <li>
     item here
   </li>
   <li>
     item here
   </li>
   <li>
     item here
   </li>
</ul>
```

Or this one:

```
<p>
   Content...
</p>
```

Into this:

```
<ul>
   <li>item here</li>
   <li>item here</li>
   <li>item here</li>
</ul>
```

And this:

```
 <p>Content...</p>
```

Having the content of every tag in a separate line from the opening/closing tags is a waste of space for me.

Any idea how to accomplish this either by modifying something in TidyHTML or manually, or any other way for that matter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, after reading the issues list in github, seems it's not possible:

https://github.com/welovewordpress/SublimeHtmlTidy/issues/24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Note: This solution works only in ST2, because at this moment (7/31/14) HTMLTidy is not available for ST3.

I figured a temporary solution, not ideal by any means, but...

1. Go to: `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User`. You will be editing the file ***Default (Windows).sublime-keypmap***.
2. Add these two instructions to that file (note that the instructions need to be **inside** the **[ ]** brackets):

   ```
    [
      { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "reindent" , "args": {"single_line": false}},
      //Indent code -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/formatting-html-code-using-sublime-text-2

      { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+t"], "command": "html_tidy"}
      //HTMLTidy key binding
    ]
   ```
3. Save the file.
4. Make sure you have **HTMLTidy** installed. Open HTMLTidy's Settings file ***HtmlTidy.sublime-settings***: `Preferences -> Package Settings -> HtmlTidy -> Settings - Default`.
5. Look for `"indent": true,` (include double quotes and comma) and change it to `false`.
6. Save the file.
7. Go back to your HTML file and select **a section** of the code you want to format in one line. Yes, it doesn't work if you select the entire markup o_O. It will only leave what's inside the `<body>` tag, and it will delete everything else (`<html>`, `<head>`, etc).
8. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to execute TidyHTML. This will shrink your markup and make the tags in one line.
9. Finally press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to execute the indentation.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

If your elements are uniform, a much easier solution would be to select all the `<li>`s you want to crush to one line with <kbd>alt+f3</kbd> or, for more control, <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd>, then just hit <kbd>ctrl+j</kbd> twice to join the lines together. Done!

Failing that, use <kbd>ctrl+shift+j</kbd> to select all the content within a tag after multi-selecting one part of each of the tags. Hit the cursors to the right or left edge with the left or right arrow keys and you can delete from there.

Comment: Your solution seems pretty good, I tested with some basic HTML and it seemed to work for the most part. I'll keep your suggestions in mind and compare it to the solution I came up with, and decide after then which solution is the best. Gave you an upvote. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Cheers! Watch out for this, though: if the line ends on a quote (single or double), it won't insert a space.

Comment: Nice! exactly what I need... +1

Answer (score 0):

you can set shortcut key for one line by press key F12

goto menu Preferences -> Key Bindings – User

```
{ "keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent"}
```

see detail at  http://how-to-sublime-text.blogspot.com/2014/11/reformat-code.html

Comment: This is only for re-indentation. Also, the solution on that blog is the same one from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/how-do-i-reformat-html-code-using-sublime-text-2. Thanks for the note though.