# How to format "one line html" as a pretty document in sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have a html source file containing only one line like the following:

```
<html><head>test</head><body>wow</body></html>
```

, and I want to format it as following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        test
    </head>
    <body>
        wow
    </body>
</html>
```

, I have used the command: Edit-> Line-> Reindent but it doesn't work.

Comment: Check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143850/sublime-text-2-format-html-tags-content-in-one-line

Comment: for st2 there are several plugins, that format html code. im using a plugin called "tag": https://github.com/SublimeText/Tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Sublime Text try this:

1. Highlight the last character in the first tag: "`>`"
2. Use `Find` > `Quick Add Next` (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on PC)

You'll now have all occurrences highlighted in multiple selections, move the caret to the end of the tag and hit return to insert all the new lines you require.

Good luck

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `Quick Add Next` command at all. Great idea!

Answer (score 4):

I was under the impression that Sublime provided this ability as well. When I found out that it wasn't, I had the idea of using regular expressions. Even though regex are usually considered inappropriate for parsing XML/HTML, I found this approach to be acceptable in this case. Sublime is also said to be highly customizable by plugins, so I think this would be a way.

#### Sublime Plugins

To be honest, I could have thought of [`tidy`](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) or at least suspect that there must be plugins out there dealing with your issue. Instead I ended up writing my first sublime plugin. I have only tested it with your input and expected output, which it satisfied, but it is most certainly far from working reliably. However, I post it here to share what I've learned and it's still an answer to the problem.

Opening a new buffer (<kbd>Ctrl+n</kbd>) and choosing the '*New Plugin...*' entry in the Menu '*Tools*' generously generates a little 'Hello World!' example plugin (as a Python module), which gives a great template for implementing a `sublime_plugin.TextCommand` subclass. A TextCommand provides access to an active buffer/currently open file. Like its relatives `WindowCommand` and `ApplicationCommand`, it is required to overwrite a run-method.

The [official API Reference](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) suggests learning by reading the example sources distributed with the Sublime builds and located in `Packages/Default` relative to the Sublime config path. Further examples can be found on the [website](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-examples). There's [more](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/how-to-create-a-sublime-text-2-plugin/) [on](http://blog.petrockblock.com/2012/05/16/writing-a-plugin-for-sublime-text-2-enhancing-the-matlab-plugin/) the internet.

#### Processing selected text

To get to a solution for your issue, we primarily need access to a [`View`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.View) object which represents an active text buffer. Fortunately, the `TextCommand` subclass we are about to implement has one, and we can conveniently ask it for the currently selected regions and their selection contents, process selected text conforming our needs and replace the selected text with our preference afterwards.

To sum up the string operations: There are four regular expressions, each of which matches one of the element classes `<start-tag>`, `<empty-tag/>`, `</close-tag>` and `text-node`. Assuming that all of our markup text is covered by these, we did each line in selection into matching substrings. These are then realigned one-per-line. Having done this, we apply simple indentation by remembering to indent every line whose predecessor contains a start tag. Lines containing end tags are unindented immediately.

Using the [group addressing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups) features of Python regex, we can determine the indentation of every line and align the next one accordingly. This, with no further ado, will result in internally consistent indented markup, but with no consideration of the lines outside the selection. By extending the selection to an enclosing element, or at least complying with the indentation levels of the adjacent lines, one could easily improve the results. Its always possible to make use of the [default commands](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/commands).

Another thing to take care of is binding keys to the plugin command and contributing menu entries. It is probably possible [somehow](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/menus), and the default `.sublime-menu`and `.sublime-commands` files in `Packages/Default` at least give an idea. Anyway, here's some code. It has to be saved under `Packages/User/whatever.py` and can be called from the Sublime Python Console (<kbd>Ctrl+`` ` ``</kbd>) like this: `view.run_command('guess_indentation')`.

#### Code

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import re

class GuessIndentationCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        #view.begin_edit()
        # patterns
        start_tag = '<\w+(?:\s+[^>\/]+)*\s*>'       # tag_start
        node_patterns = [start_tag, 
                        start_tag[:-1]+'\/\s*>',    # tag_empty
                        '<\/\s?\w+\s?>',            # tag_close
                        '[^>\s][^<>]*[^<\s]']       # text_node
        patterns = '(?:{0})'.format('|'.join(node_patterns))
        indentors = re.compile('[ \t]*({0})'.format('|'.join(node_patterns[:1])))
        unindentors=re.compile('[ \t]*({0})'.format(node_patterns[2]))
        # process selected text
        for region in view.sel():
            # if selection contains text:
            if not region.empty():
                selection = view.substr(region)
                expanded = []
                # divide selected lines into XML elements, if it contains more than one
                for line in selection.split('\n'):
                    elements = re.findall(patterns, line)
                    if len(elements)>0:
                        expanded += elements
                    else:
                        expanded.append(line)
                # indent output
                indent=0
                indented = []
                for line in expanded:
                    match = unindentors.match(line)
                    if match:
                        indent = max(0, indent-1)
                    # append line to output, unindented if closing tag
                    indented.append('\t'*indent+line)
                    if match:
                        continue
                    # test for possible indentation candidate
                    # indentation applies to the NEXT line
                    match = indentors.match(line)
                    if match:
                        indent+=1
                # replace selection with aligned output
                view.replace(edit, region, '\n'.join(indented))
```

Comment: This is appropriate solution. Despite this may looks hard to perform - acutally can be completed in 1 min. Short version of an answer (for mac os): 1. Select Tools->Developer->New plugin 2. Copy and paste code above into workspace appeared 3. Select File->Save as, name it guess_indentation.py 4. Open a tab with your HTML code 5. Select View->Console 6. Type view.run_command('guess_indentation') 7. Select Edit->Line->Reindent 8. Upvote that guy for such a brilliant solution

Answer (score 0):

if its for something simple, i was able to record a macro (tools -> record macro) indenting the tags and then save it and reuse this macro. not sure if that helps any though.