# How do I enable smart HTML tag indenting in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: html, tags, sublimetext2, indentation, sublimetext3

I don't remember exactly when this functionality stopped working, but I always had Sublime Text do auto indenting properly. For example, if I type `<div>` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the caret would automatically make a tab on the next line. Similarly, when I closed tags, they would automatically un-indent by one tab (such as when pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> in order to close a tag).

This functionality seems to have disappeared, at least in ST3, and I can't find any way to get it back. Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: it might be useful to add that PHP auto-indenting works just fine, such as making indentation between brackets.

Answer (score 3):

You can install "Tag" plugin using [package control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation). [This question](https://superuser.com/q/564180/142663) suggests the plugin has issues, but I haven't noticed any that would be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Possible duplicate:

[How do I reformat HTML code using Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/how-do-i-reformat-html-code-using-sublime-text-2)

See [dardub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302760/dardub)'s answer...

OR better yet (just noticed that!) [peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923315/peter)'s answer:

Just select all lines (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and then from the menu select Edit → Line → Reindent. This will work if your file is saved with an extension that contains HTML like .html or .php.

** for me it worked on ***ST3***

Comment: This enables you to tidy up code once you're finished working with it, but doesn't auto indent while you write your code (what the OP is looking for). I'm not entirely sure how useful code formatting is once you've finished writing it :)