# Sorting code by family order

Tags: sorting

I dont know exactly how is it called, but I saw on some youtube tutorials that there is a way to sort code by family. I mean, if u have some code written in sublime text 2 ignoring family order, you can just select it and press some hotkey to sort it. Im really new to coding and i dont know how to make it clearer.

I googled it but I havent found anything.

Like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
</head>
<body>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

To this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you asking about pretty-printing HTML? http://infohound.net/tidy/

Comment: This is not a coding question, but I think it belongs in the meta part of this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you're trying to do is probably called "auto-indenting" or "auto-formatting".

You might find this question and answer helpful: [How do I reformat HTML code using Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/formatting-html-code-using-sublime-text-2). According to it, Edit > Line > Reindent should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is formatting code :).

In sublime text go to Tools->Command Palette(or press Ctrl+Shift+P) and then type Reindent Lines and press enter.