# How to proper format/indent HTML and PHP Code in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

im wondering if there is any Sublime Text 3 plugin besides HTML Tidy which is able to reindent or reformat parts of HTML Code

Comment: Potential solutions discussing sublime text 2, but i doubt that the functionality has changed very much:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/how-do-i-reformat-html-code-using-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your answer, but i found a nice, built in approach of sublime text. Just select everything (CTRL + a (Windows) or CMD + a (Mac) and click this in the menu

Edit → Line → Reindent

maybe this helps also others

EDIT(2017): You can also use key combination (without need for mouse)

```
CTRL + SHIFT + P (Windows)
CMD + SHIFT + P (Mac)
```

then type 'Reindent' and select the fist option 'Indentation: Reindent Lines'

Comment: Note that this only re-indents code and doesn't take care of any other re-formatting issues

Comment: This didn't work for me for sublime 3 php files. It does work for html, css and js though.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [`HTML-CSS-JS Prettify`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify). It requires [nodejs](http://nodejs.org) be installed and in your `PATH`, but once you get that set up properly it works great. Make sure you read **all** of the docs, though.