# Is there a CTRL + SHIFT + F for sublime like eclipse shortcut?

Tags: html, eclipse, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

(CTRL + SHIFT + F) it's really a nice shortcut to keep code well organized in eclipse. Is there any thing equivalent for sublime text editor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/how-do-i-reformat-html-code-using-sublime-text-2

Comment: Where is locate this key mapping file in windows?

Comment: There is no default key binding for it. You can create a User key binding by going to `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime has an build-in feature that does indent lines for you. You can find this when opening the `command palette`, then look for `Indentation: Reindent Lines`.
Specific actions to organize your code is harder, because of the different syntaxes of languages.

Luckily enough, Will Bond has been so nice to create a Package Manager for Sublime Text. Using this, features can be added into the editor. These packages do  can add code formatting features. You can see [a list of `formatting packages` here](https://sublime.wbond.net/browse/labels/formatting).

As one of the tags in your question contains `HTML`, I'll assume you're looking for a formatting tool for HTML. I've found a package for that, although I've got no personal experience with it. You may [install it from here](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/HTMLBeautify).

> A plugin for Sublime Text , that formats (indents) HTML source code. It makes code easier for humans to read.

I would recommend reading through the docs for more information about the package.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't a default key binding equivalent to CTRL + SHIFT + F in eclise. However, there is the reindent command that can be used to make your own key binding.

Open the "Key Bindings - User" from your preferences and add this JSON:

```
[
{
    "keys": ["CTRL+\\"],
    "command": "reindent",
    "args": {
        "single_line": false
    },
    "context": [{
        "key": "selector",
        "operator": "not_equal",
        "operand": "source.js,source.json,text.html"
    }]
}, {
    "keys": ["CTRL+\\"],
    "command": "htmlprettify",
    "context": [{
        "key": "selector",
        "operator": "equal",
        "operand": "text.html"
    }]
}, {
    "keys": ["CTRL+\\"],
    "command": "js_format",
    "context": [{
        "key": "selector",
        "operator": "equal",
        "operand": "source.js,source.json"
    }]
}
]
```

This will bind -\ to the reindent command (CTRL + SHIFT + F is already taken by "Find in Files"). single_line is false to force it to reindent the whole page, just like in eclipse.

There are two additional variants of the key bindings for working with HTML and JavaScript. These require that you have the htmlprettify and js_format plugins installed. I found the default formatting inferior for HTML and Javascript, so if you are editing these files I do recommend the plugins. If you don't care about these formats, then you can delete the last two key binding entries.

Answer (score 3):

Go to "preferences/Key Bindings" and add on the right panel this line

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}
```

that line is meant for indenting all your code in one shot so you would ctrl+a then ctrl+shift+f

Answer (score 1):

you can set shortcut key for one line by press [ctrl+shift+f] easy!!!

goto menu Preferences -> Key Bindings – User

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f"], "command": "reindent"}
```

see detail at  http://how-to-sublime-text.blogspot.com/2014/11/reformat-code.html