# Where can I find a PHP editor with text format that actually works?

Tags: php, code-editor, php-ide

I'm using TextWrangler and I can't find a good code formatter. I tried TextMate and it ruined my code completely.

I don't care about anything else other than a button that formats the text. From this:

```
function hello() {

if ($statement) {

die();

}

}
```

To this:

```
function hello() {

    if ($statement) {

        die();

    }

}
```

Without having to press "Tab" 4 times.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I don't use auto-formatters, but I think NetBeans does a good job. Depends if you are OK with a relatively heavy-weight IDE.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is an IDE, I use and recommend PhpStorm by JetBrains

Comment: Takes more time to format text, instead of writing it. NOT KIDDING!

Comment: (The purpose of editors improving questions is two-fold: it makes them easier to read for new readers, and also sends a signal to the OP as to how we like questions here. They are best succinct, and, of course, following the guidelines).

Comment: (Commentary on votes and posting guidelines does not belong in questions. Please add that, if you must, as comments. If you are interested, you may also post to or read [the Meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), if you wish to get involved in how Stack Overflow is run.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Your question is opinion based, so there is not a real answer.

But, if you want a text editor then use Sublime Text.

It's very powerful. and very customizeable.

After you've installed it, you can create a shortcut to indent your code.

The link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/how-do-i-reformat-html-code-using-sublime-text-2).

Comment: *"Your question is opinion based"* - Yes and no, it's about asking for software, which is what the question was closed as.

Comment: *"This is not a matter of opinion. If you don't use text format and instead you write code the same way you would eat a sandwich, you are retarded. –  user3737190 5 secs ago"* - sure hope that wasn't aimed at me ;-) @user3737190 edit as per your edit: *"f**king Tab button over and over and over again"* - oh, how lovely.

Comment: @user3737190: for "retarded", have a downvote and a moderator report. We don't use that sort of discriminatory language here.