# How can I insert a return at every HTML break "> <"

Tags: html, css

So I've never encountered this personally - I have a huge blob of HTML with inline CSS that I need to break up to be cohesive and editable (it's literally all back to back right now with no returns in any of the lines).

I use Sublime and I'm trying to insert a return at every break of code so I can easily go through and edit it all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reformat HTML code using Sublime Text 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/how-do-i-reformat-html-code-using-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a lot of code you can do it manually.

Otherwise just select all lines (Ctrl A) and then from the menu select Edit → Line → Reindent. This works with any files with the file extension `.php` or `.html`.

Comment: The Reindent feature isn't working for me, I think it's because it has a TON of inline css.

Comment: Would It be possible to copy the css delete it and then do "Edit → Line → Reindent" after reindenting, paste back in the css, if that dose noy work you always can undo it.