# Auto Complete in Sublime

Tags: html, autocomplete, sublimetext3

When I write HTML in Sublime Text 3, when I write div or class it auto completes to: div="hi" and class="hi".

I would like it to autocomplete to: div = "hi" and class = "hi"

I like to have spaces in the code so it is neater to read.

Anyway to do this?

Comment: Writing it in such a way once, should have the program suggest/autocomplete it like that the next time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reformat HTML code using Sublime Text 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/how-do-i-reformat-html-code-using-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what do you want is 
`<div class="hi">`, right?
Well if you got EMMET in your IDE is too easy
`div[class="hi"]` or `div.hi`