# How can I auto-format code which contains no line breaks or indentation?

Tags: excel, regex, parsing, format, sublimetext3

When working with any Excel function that goes more than a few levels deep, it quickly becomes hard to read in the single-line format Excel presents them in:
`=IF(F3,24*IF(AC3,IF(ROW()=16,V3,MIN(IF(OR(1440*SUMIF(AC3:AC$16,TRUE,U3:U$16)>=1440*V3,NOT(AC3)),U3,IF(1440*SUMIF(AC3:AC$16,TRUE,Z3:Z$16)>=1440*V3,Z3,AA3)),V3)),U3),"")`

So what I'll often do is, I'll pop it into Sublime and indent it like code, making it immediately easier to analyze:

```vb
=IF(
    F3,
    24*IF(
        AC3,
        IF(
            ROW()=16,
            V3,
            MIN(
                IF(
                    OR(
                        1440*SUMIF(AC3:AC$16,TRUE,U3:U$16)>=1440*V3,
                        NOT(AC3)
                    ),
                    U3,
                    IF(
                        1440*SUMIF(AC3:AC$16,TRUE,Z3:Z$16)>=1440*V3,
                        Z3,
                        AA3
                    )
                ),
                V3
            )
        ),
        U3
    ),
    ""
)
```

I've done this enough times that it would save me time to automate it. I started trying to write a regex to do it, something along the lines of:

find `((?: {4})*)(.*?)\b(IF|AND|OR|MIN|MAX)\(` replace `\1\2\3(\n    \1`

But I couldn't get it to work because regex struggled with the recursive indentation. I found a Sublime package that can bundle a series of separate regexes into a single operation, which might work but I'm not sure how I'd approach it.

How can I auto-indent my code like this? Are there any possible alternate approaches I may not know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is something that remain same all over programming languages. So you can simply use above regex in your preferred lang.

```php
<?php

$data = '
=IF(F3,24*IF(AC3,IF(ROW()=16,V3,MIN(IF(OR(1440*SUMIF(AC3:AC$16,TRUE,U3:U$16)>=1440*V3,NOT(AC3)),U3,IF(1440*SUMIF(AC3:AC$16,TRUE,Z3:Z$16)>=1440*V3,Z3,AA3)),V3)),U3),"")
';

$pattern = "/IF\((.*)\)/i"; //find string starting with "IF(" and ends with ")"
$ident = 4;

while(preg_match($pattern, $data,$match) == 1) //If matches 
{
   preg_match($pattern, $data, $match);
   $spaces = str_repeat(' ', $ident); //Generate space with length of ident
   $data =  str_replace($match[1],"\n".$spaces.$match[1]."\n".$spaces,$data); 
   $ident += 4; //Increase ident by 4
}
echo $data; //Now output data
?>
```

This would output:

```vb
=IF(
    F3,24*IF(
        AC3,IF(
            ROW()=16,V3,MIN(IF(
                OR(1440*SUMIF(
                    AC3:AC$16,TRUE,U3:U$16)>=1440*V3,NOT(AC3)),U3,IF(
                        1440*SUMIF(
                            AC3:AC$16,TRUE,Z3:Z$16
                            )>=1440*V3,Z3,AA3
                        )
                    ),V3
                )
            ),U3
        ),""
    )
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b97c528312c03ef556efe3e637e200b73da312e0

Comment: I see, to make things easier you're using regex from within another language, which adds the ability to use helpful constructs like variables.
Part of my difficulty was because I was using the Sublime editor's "find and replace" style regex, as opposed to a language where I could just include an iteration variable like you did.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: @DavidS. its regex. Means it can be used in sublime text as well.

Comment: Right, the problem I ran into was, as Sublime is just a text editor, I can only use the regex itself, not any of the helper code you used with it, such as the str_repeat and the $ident variable.

Comment: @DavidS. Does above link helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888837/14919621

Comment: Yeah, I tried it out and it's not too bad. Not quite perfect either, but if I just regex line breaks next to every parenthesis `(?<=\()|(?=\))` then use reindent then I get something mostly okay.

Comment: Exactly, you can achieve it in several ways. Your method is more simpler and user friendly. Whereas, my method is programmer-only thing. Have good day !

Comment: You can also post your own answer and mark as tick.